# Get value of bit fields

Tags: c, bit-fields

```
unsigned value( unsigned n, unsigned low, unsigned high ){
    if( !(low <= high && high <= 32) )  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    if( low == 0 && high == 32 )
        return n;
    else
        return n >> low & (1U << (high-low)) - 1;
}
```

imagine we had the following as n=11100011, low=2, and high=7.

by the time we reached the return statement I'd have this

00111000 & (00100000 - 00000001)

this would be

00111000 & 00011111

which would equal

00011000

but thats not right is it? Thats 24 while I want 00111000 which is 56

what am I doing wrong here? where did I screw up?

Comment: I don't know.  What is the purpose of this function?  (i.e. what is the rule that gives you 56?)

Comment: the function gets the value of the specified bitfield. at least it's supposed to.

Comment: Your left-shift has an off-by-one error.  See my answer below.

Comment: OH WOW. i am blind as a bat. hahaha i feel stupid thanks :P For whatever reason I had this in my mind (high, low]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to left-shift one more position before you subtract 1.  That will extend the string of `1` bits one more position to the left, which is where the `high` bit resides.

```
return (n >> low) & ((1U << (high-low+1)) - 1);
```

Imagine the extreme case, where `low = 0` and `high = 32`.  Ignore the overflow, which is an artifact of the size of `long`, and do the calculation:

```
(n >> 0) & ((1U << 33) - 1)
```

The term on the left is just `n`, and the term on the right is a string of 32 `1` bits.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an off by one error:

```
n >> low = 11100011 >> 2 = 111000 = 56
```

Then to mask off the high bits, you're ANDing with `high-low` ones:

```
111000 & (1 << 5)-1
```

But `(1 << 5)-1 =  11111`, but you really want `111111` (otherwise you're ANDing out the leading bit, effectively subtracting 32 from the value).  So instead, use:

```
return n >> low & (1U << (high - low + 1)) - 1;
```